Livewire V3 testing "Component has no errors." in testsuite
I'm working in a Laravel 11 project using Livewire V3. I have a component called MonitorCreate component and corresponding class. The class implements the form object. When I submit the form, I get validation errors, but my test doesn't see any errors, what am I missing?

Component has no errors.

My test
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Livewire\Site\Pages\Monitors;

use App\Livewire\Site\Pages\Monitors\MonitorCreate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Livewire\Livewire;
use Tests\TestCase;

class MonitorCreateTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_component_can_submit_form_and_see_validation_errors_successfully(): void
    {
        Livewire::test(MonitorCreate::class)
            ->call('submit')
            ->assertHasErrors('form.name');

    }

    public function test_component_renders_successfully()
    {
        Livewire::test(MonitorCreate::class)
            ->assertStatus(200);
    }
}

My form object
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Site\Pages\Monitors;

use App\Livewire\Site\Forms\Monitors\MonitorForm;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Models\Monitor;

class MonitorCreate extends Component
{
    public MonitorForm $form;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->form->responseStatusCodes = collect(array_keys(Response::$statusTexts))->toArray();
    }

    public function addStatusCode(string $type = 'down', int $code = 200): void
    {
        $property = 'custom_http_' . $type . '_statuses';

        if (in_array($code, $this->form->$property)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->form->$property[] = $code;
    }

    public function removeStatusCode(string $type = 'down', int $code = 200): void
    {
        $property = 'custom_http_' . $type . '_statuses';

        if (! in_array($code, $this->form->$property)) {
            return;
        }

        $index = array_search($code, $this->form->$property);
        if ($index !== false) {
            unset($this->form->$property[$index]);
        }
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Monitor::class);

        $this->form->validate();

        $monitor = $this->form->create();

        $this->redirect(route('page.account.monitors.index'), navigate: true);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.site.pages.monitors.monitor-create');
    }
}


